# How to modify default docker base image during deployment of Azure Kubernetes service

Tags: azure, docker, opencv, kubernetes, azure-machine-learning-service

I have been using DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE as my base image in Azure ML but now it started throwing the
`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` error when importing opencv.
Some answers here on stackoverflow say i need to run apt-get update on the image. specifically:

```
RUN apt-get update ##[edited] 
RUN apt-get install 'ffmpeg'\
'libsm6'\ 
'libxext6'  -y
```

Would you know where can i find the docker file to add the lines to  or is there a way to patch the image during the deployment of the AKS service? (same way as pip and conda packages are possible to be installed during the deployment)

Answer (score 0):

The base images for AzureML containers can be found in this [github](https://github.com/Azure/AzureML-Containers) project.
This page also contains detailed documentation for the images.

Alternatively you can use "docker inspect" to get details of the image.

For example: `docker inspect mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base-gpu:latest`

Then in the base image like this [dockerfile](https://github.com/Azure/AzureML-Containers/blob/master/base/gpu/intelmpi2018.3-cuda10.0-cudnn7-ubuntu16.04/Dockerfile#L28-L54) just add packages you need along with other dependencies like in this:

```
    # custom packages <------
    apt-get install -y \
    ffmpeg \ 
    libsm6 \ 
    libxext6 && \
```

```
# Install Common Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # SSH and RDMA
    libmlx4-1 \
    libmlx5-1 \
    librdmacm1 \
    libibverbs1 \
    libmthca1 \
    libdapl2 \
    dapl2-utils \
    openssh-client \
    openssh-server \
    iproute2 && \
    # custom packages <------
    apt-get install -y \
    ffmpeg \ 
    libsm6 \ 
    libxext6 && \
    # Others
    apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
...
```